# For the given ideals $I=\langle i\rangle$ and $J=\langle j\rangle$ find a suitable $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $I+J=\langle f\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Given $i= x^2+2x+3 , j= x^3+x+1$ we have to find some $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $I+J =\langle f\rangle.$

As I couldn't make any significant head way to the solution so I am leaving this problem entirely to this forum. Please help me.

Comment: Not easily readable... Edit is necessary...

Comment: From my side its readable, I don't know what to do.

Comment: may be you could make  "i= x2+2x+3" into $i=x^2+2x+3$ and that $x$ in $I+J$ to $f$ and the rest also......

Comment: I don't know how to use the codes

Comment: Yes I thought of that but could not think of a way of expressing I+J in the required form.

Comment: Will you kindly take some more trouble to explain the solution to me. I am yet to get it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As was already said in the comments, you have to compute the greatest divisor $f$ using the extended euclidean algorithm. The resulting Bezoutian identity

$$f=a\cdot i+b\cdot j$$

then proves the nontrivial direction of the ideal identity.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be easy/efficient/advisable all the time to "Compute"  greatest common divisor of two polynomials.

Better idea would be to check if at least one of the polynomial is irreducible..

Once you see one of the polynomial is irreducible....

this should immediately tell you what g.c.d should be...

> If a polynomial is irreducible, what are its factors?

Now, coming to this problem..

Is $x^2+2x+3$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$??

Is $x^3+x+1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$??

Note : You can not use this idea if only one polynomial out of two is irreducible and that irreducible polynomial is of degree strictly less than that of the second polynomial.